# Word fields - IF statement not working as expected due to quote/speech marks

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, field-codes

I've got a couple of merge fields that are using this syntax

```
{ IF {DOCVARIABLE "variable1" } = "" "" "(the {QUOTE 34}{DOCVARIABLE "variable2" }{QUOTE 34})"  }
```

If `variable1` is empty, it should do nothing but it always inserts the 'false' text, like this: `(the "variable2")`. I have checked the value of `variable1` and it is showing as empty. `variable2`'s value always shows.

Have I got the wrong syntax? I've checked over it several times and I'm using the exact same thing elsewhere and it's working. I'm wondering if it's something to do with using `{QUOTE 34}` to insert quotes, which is confusing Word? Is there another way to escape double quotes?

Comment: If should be included in {} press Ctrl +F9

Comment: It is, sorry that didn't copy across for some reason. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Try { IF {DOCVARIABLE "variable1" } = "" "" "(the" {QUOTE 34}{DOCVARIABLE "variable2" }{QUOTE 34} ")"  }

Comment: That half works. It keeps `(the` and drops the rest if the variable is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
{ IF {DOCVARIABLE variable1 } = "" "" "(the {QUOTE 34} {DOCVARIABLE variable2 }{QUOTE 34})"  }
```

Remove the quotes surrounding variable1 and variable2
Always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>

- Before starting the If
- Before writing DocVariable variable1
- Before writing DocVariable variable2
- Quote 34
  Create the variable1 and 2 in Fields before Formula
  Run your VBA code to set values to the variable and Update Fields
  Keep in mind if variable1 is string empty is ""
  if variable1 is number null is 0

Comment: I entered it exactly as you said but it still shows `(the "")` in the document if the variable is empty! I may need to look at different formatting or populate the variable with something else so i can verify its contents

Comment: Where do you assign values to the variable1 and 2?

Comment: In a C# application that passes all the values to word. I have displayed all the docvariables and can see that this one is empty. The same if statements work elsewhere in the document but don't have the `QUOTE 34` parts

Comment: I have try it with VBA and it gave me (the " Citation")

Comment: Got it working by setting the field to 0, if nothing is entered. Then checking for that instead of blank. I had to use your syntax though

Answer (score 1):

When using this {QUOTE 34} you need to use the F9 key to show the results. And if you are in a mail merge document, you might need to toggle the mail merge "Preview Results" ribbon action item.